# What is the best way to access SOAP WebServices from portable native code?

Tags: web-services, soap, native-code

I need to access a SOAP webservice (written in .NET with MS SQL backend, FWIW) from several different platforms, so my common denominator is native C++.  Is there a portable library for this or I should roll my own solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do SOAP in C++ you need both a networking and an XML/SOAP library. These aren't easy to find, especially if cross-platform is needed.

I would start from [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html). There seems to be a SOAP example [available](http://www.vivtek.com/wftk/doc/code/wftk/action/ACTION_http.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that using Java rather than C++ might actually be easier. Java does run in lots of places and has quite nice Web Service client libraries.

Is that worth a look?

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work :(.  Some of my target platforms do not have much RAM to load the Java engine without disturbing other things. But that might be a good approach for some other folks.  Thank you for your opinion!